# Issue in finding power of a number using user defined functions

Tags: c++

[MY CODE along with the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7d9o.png)

The following code is not working. It has no errors, am doing some mistake in the logic I think. I want to find power of a number using functions. How to make this code work?

The code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int pow(int);

int main()
{
    int x,p,ans;
    cout<<"Enter a number";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Enter the power of the number";
    cin>>p;
    ans=pow(x);
    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}

int pow(int)
{
    int a=1,i,p,x;

    for(i=0;i<=p;i++)
    {
        a=a*x;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: You should at least be able to give examples of input and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I have attached the pic

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  Usually, using a debugger is a lot faster than posting to StackOverflow and waiting for a reply.

Comment: Please rename your function so it doesn't conflict with [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow). *Although it technically doesn't because yours uses integers*.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Am sorry. As I said, am a complete beginner. I don't even know what debugging is, will read about it, thanks.

Comment: Please post in your question your **INPUT** and your **EXPECTED OUTPUT** not an image with what is currently happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int pow(int, int);

int main()
{
    int x,p,ans;
    cout<<"Enter a number";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Enter the power of the number";
    cin>>p;
    ans=pow(x, p);
    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}

int pow(int x, int p)
{
    int a=1,i;
    for(i=0;i<=p;i++)
    {
        a=a*x;
    }
    return a;
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/nuQQLu)

You have to pass the local variables into the function instead of defining new ones with the same name. What you are doing should give you warnings about unused variables (`x` and `p` in `main`) and it also invokes undefined behavior in `pow` because of ininitialized reads of the variables defined there.

Also your function was wrong. You were just multiplying 1 with a value a bunch of times, which stays 1 forever.

Answer (score 1):

Your function must have the parameters names specified (not just the types):

`int pow(int) -> int pow(int b, int p)`

You iterate once more than necessary:

```
for (i = 0; i <= p; i++) -> for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
```

You can shorten some arithmetic operations:

```
a=a*x -> a *= x;
```

The final function:

```
int pow(int b, int p)
{
    int a = 1, i;
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
        a *= b;
    return a;
}
```

You call it by passing the variables precedently declared:

```
pow(x, p)
```

So your final code be like:

```
#include <iostream>

int pow(int b, int p)
{
    int a = 1, i;
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
        a *= b;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int x, p, ans;
    std::cin >> x >> p;
    ans = pow(x, p);
    std::cout << ans << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lastly, the name of the function should be changed to avoid conflicts with [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Comment: Indeed, also the variables could had better naming and the 'i' variable could be declared inside the for loop. Also the 'ans' variable could be easily omitted.